# WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading method not with reactjs site

Tags: android, reactjs, webview

I have a reactjs page site and i want load it in `WebView` Android. I want handle link clicked when user click into any link or button by handle method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. However, this method not called when user clicked into link. It call only first time when page loading.

I handle like this:

```
     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Uri uri = request.getUrl();
                if (uri == null) return true;
                Log.e("JJ", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading1: " + uri.toString());
                ...
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("JJ", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading2: " + url);
            ....
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("JJ", "onPageFinished: " + url);
            stopLoadingView();
        }
    });
```

Have any problem here? Have any suggestion for my problem?